# Cron jobs creating logs in home directory

Tags: php, cron

I had my cron job (update_check_s1.php) running every minute. Some files with same name prefix are created in my home directory every minute, but those files are empty.

Example:

update_check_s1.php.1

update_check_s1.php.2

update_check_s1.php.3

.
.
.

update_check_s1.php.12336

update_check_s1.php.12337

etc...
As on image shown [here](https://ibb.co/60jqnkc).
How can I prevent this from happening? And can somebody explain what is exactly happening?

Here is my cronjob code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName, 3306);
if($mysqli->connect_error) {
  exit('Could not connect');
}

$sql = "SELECT updates, heading_ser, paragraph_ser, heading_eng, paragraph_eng, destroy_date, id 
FROM update_slides WHERE id = 1 ";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($updates, $heading_ser, $paragraph_ser, $heading_eng, $paragraph_eng, $destroy_date, $id);
$stmt->fetch();



$nowDate = date('Y-m-d');

 if ( $destroy_date > 0 & $destroy_date < $nowDate ) {
    $sql2 = "UPDATE update_slides SET heading_ser='', paragraph_ser='', heading_eng='', paragraph_eng='', destroy_date='0000-00-00', updates=updates+1  WHERE id=1";

        $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare($sql2);
        $stmt2->execute();      
 }

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Please supply the code that you execute with the cron job.

Comment: Thats not actually my problem. The code is doing what it should. Its working perfectly. But I don't know what are those files and why are those created in my home directory when my cronjob files are in some other directory.

Comment: Are you sure your code doesn't create these files?

Comment: please expose your cron job code. so community can help you

Comment: I have added the php code

Comment: Can you also share your crontab file?

Comment: I am having trouble finding it. Where should I look for crontab files in cpanel?

Comment: You should have edited it :-|   https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/advanced/cron-jobs/

Comment: On the link provided there is no information about crontab file?